# Javascript dynamic creatationg of anchor tag is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to create html with JavaScript. but my link to anchor tag is not working as expected.

```
  var test ="http://blogs.edweek.org/edweek/finding_common_ground/2016/10/if_coaching_is_so_powerful_why_are't_principals_being_coached.html?cmp=SOC-EDIT-FB";

    var res ="<a style='color:#7Bc76B;text-decoration: none;' target='_blank' href='"+test+"'>Link to read more ></a>";

    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = res;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b4kqsn6u/

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: what is issue ??and what do you want plz briefly example

Comment: link is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply modify your `<a>` declaration as follows to take care of single quote present in your URL:

```
var res ='<a style="color:#7Bc76B;text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" href="'+test+'">Link to read more ></a>';
```

declared within single quote as above and all attributes are within double quotes

https://jsfiddle.net/b4kqsn6u/3/

Answer (score 0):

You have a single quote (') in your URL that doesn't belong there. Make sure you urlencode your URLs either beforehand by replacing single quotes by %27 or do it manually (encodeURI does not encode single quotes):

```
var test ="http://blogs.edweek.org/edweek/finding_common_ground/2016/10/if_coaching_is_so_powerful_why_aren't_principals_being_coached.html?cmp=SOC-EDIT-FB";

test = test.replace(/'/g, "%27");

var res ="<a style='color:#7Bc76B;text-decoration: none;' target='_blank' href='"+test+"'>Link to read more ></a>";

document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = res;
```

Comment: http://blogs.edweek.org/edweek/finding_common_ground/2016/10/if_coaching_is_so_powerful_why_are%27t_principals_being_coached.html?cmp=SOC-EDIT-FB  this is not working

Comment: It is working. Your original URL points to http://blogs.edweek.org/edweek/finding_common_ground/2016/10/if_coaching_is_so_powerful_why_are't_principals_being_coached.html?cmp=SOC-EDIT-FB which gives you a 404. If you link to a non-available website, you get what you'd expect ;-) The error you had before was that the single quote disrupted your URL because it ended the href attribute prematurely.

Comment: http://blogs.edweek.org/edweek/finding_common_ground/2016/10/if_coaching_is_so_powerful_why_are't_principals_being_coached.html?cmp=SOC-EDIT-FB  this is working

Comment: and after you code not working

Comment: This is not working :-) You are missing an "n" in your url:

Comment: http://blogs.edweek.org/edweek/finding_common_ground/2016/10/if_coaching_is_so_powerful_why_aren't_principals_being_coached.html?cmp=SOC-EDIT-FB works, http://blogs.edweek.org/edweek/finding_common_ground/2016/10/if_coaching_is_so_powerful_why_are't_principals_being_coached.html?cmp=SOC-EDIT-FB does not. Just edit your URL and add an n. For your convenience I edited my answer and added the n. Try again...

Answer (score 0):

I usually put the single quote outside the double quote.the single quote will make the string not to get parsed

```js
var test ="http://blogs.edweek.org/edweek/finding_common_ground/2016/10/if_coaching_is_so_powerful_why_are't_principals_being_coached.html?cmp=SOC-EDIT-FB";

var res ='<a style="color:#7Bc76B;text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" href="'+test+'">Link to read more ></a>';

document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<div id="res">

</div>
```